# Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 unable to start Centos 7

Tags: linux, cassandra, centos

I am trying to start Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 on Centos 7 and I get error Exception:

```
ERROR [main] 2023-02-22 11:19:03,067 NativeLibraryLinux.java:64 - Failed to link the C library against JNA. Native methods will be unavailable.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-1073564104/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: /tmp/jna-1073564104/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1820)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:782)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1098)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:84)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibraryLinux.<clinit>(NativeLibraryLinux.java:55)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:95)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:212)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:633)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
WARN  [main] 2023-02-22 11:19:03,067 StartupChecks.java:136 - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
INFO  [main] 2023-02-22 11:19:03,067 StartupChecks.java:176 - JMX is enabled to receive remote connections on port: 7199
ERROR [main] 2023-02-22 11:19:03,068 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - The native library could not be initialized properly.
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider upgrading to 3.11.14.  Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 is almost 5 years old, and I'm pretty sure the JNA library is included with it.  That itself might fix this.

Otherwise, you should be able to clear out the `/tmp/jna*` files and restart.

It also might be that the Cassandra user doesn't have adequate permissions on the `/tmp` dir, so you could try redirecting that by adding this line to the end of the cassandra-env.sh file.

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$CASSANDRA_HOME/tmp"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$CASSANDRA_HOME/tmp"

Comment: @Dmitrij great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

The `UnsatisfiedLinkError` happens because Cassandra doesn't have permissions to execute the shared libraries in the `/tmp` directory (mounted with the `noexec` option).

As a workaround, you can map the JNA temporary directory by adding the following line in Cassandra's `conf/jvm.options` file:

```
-Djna.tmpdir=/path/to/jna/tmp_directory
```

Note that the Cassandra process must have read, write and execute permissions on this directory. Cheers!